# Spring Boot, R2DBC, Querydsl, query with parameter - MssqlBadGrammarException

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, querydsl, r2dbc

When I run query with parameter `Param<LocalDateTime>`, using directly SQLServer2012Templates everything works fine.
[DEBUG] [||] com.querydsl.sql.AbstractSQLQuery, shows generated query with **'?'**, but as I understand, it is not query sent to the SQL Server.

When the same query is run thru QuerydslR2dbcRepository I get exception:

**o.r2dbc.mssql.ExceptionFactory$MssqlBadGrammarException: [102] [S0001] Incorrect syntax near '?'**

dependencies:
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-r2dbc'
implementation 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-mssql'
implementation 'com.infobip:infobip-spring-data-r2dbc-querydsl-boot-starter:7.0.0'

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The R2DBC spec team explicitly decided against following the JDBC syntax for bind parameter placeholders, [see this discussion on the mailing list, which I've raised](https://groups.google.com/g/r2dbc/c/z6FcAdr441w/m/3bLdpMpHCgAJ). This means that all JDBC based libraries either:

- Have to support R2DBC explicitly, and implement the vendor specific per-driver syntax themselves
- Won't support R2DBC bind variables (inline values are still possible, of course)

From what I discovered (and documented on said mailing list), the syntax is, at least:

```sql
-- Oracle and others
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = :1
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = :name

-- SQL Server
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = @name

-- PostgreSQL
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = $1
```

Your simplest options are thus:

- Send a feature request to QueryDSL
- Patch the generated SQL on the QueryDSL level or R2DBC level, or some other level, replacing all standalone `?` markers by `$n` (this will be tricky with a regex, a simple parser that can recognise comments, string literals, etc. is probably required)
- Work with R2DBC directly